implement google opaque auth in spring boot and angular 17
I want to implement google opaque oaut in my spring boot project and I have this error ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5Bobject%20Object%5D'
I try to acces google oauthentification page to choose my email account and i expected that angular can allow me to acces google auth page
